# Comparing rates of events between an exposed and unexposed group

Tags: regression, probability, correlation, poisson-regression

I'm looking at 2 papers which are addressing the same issue using a retrospective cohort study design but use different methodology to analyse data and I would like to know why the methods used differ?

When and why would you use standardized rate ratios?

When and why would you use Poisson regression?

Comment: With an appropriate setup, Poisson regression _is_ the way to obtain inference for rate ratios, so you will need to provide more details about the methods used.